# Different between Redis and Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, redis

I am not sure what the difference between Redis and S3 is.  And if they are different, what are the ways in which they can interact?

I am aware the Redis is a key-value data store and S3 is an online web storage. To me, that sounds very similar though.  Is there a difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are completely different things.

Redis is a key-value data store as you say; S3 is a place to place files, to put it simple.
You don't treat physical files the same way as you treat databases.

Comment: both are object storage platforms, Redis is in-memory data structure store, can be used as a database, cache and message broker,  while S3 is in-disk <SSD> data structure store .

Comment: Calling Redis an object storage platform would be far from accurate. It _could_ store objects, in theory, but you'd 99.99% never use it for that.